# Error with static CSS files while deploying django app to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, django-staticfiles

I'm a new developer here, and I am trying to deploy my first web app (created using Django) and I am using Heroku. I have been getting errors with my static files and while trying to troubleshoot that I've created a few other errors and I am hitting a wall with troubleshooting the errors. Can anyone take a look at the Heroku build log and VSCode and tell me if they see anything?

I am trying to deploy my web app using Heroku. My website works fine locally but won't finish deploying. Im getting errors in the static files. I think it might have something to do with the static path.

```
 KeyError: 'collectstatic'
       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/tmp/build_0ef1ffd4/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "/tmp/build_0ef1ffd4/manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 262, in fetch_command
           settings.INSTALLED_APPS
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
           self._setup(name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup
           self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
           mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/tmp/build_0ef1ffd4/capstone/settings.py", line 15, in <module>
           import django_on_heroku
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_on_heroku'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

[Settings.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paXv5.png)

Comment: Have you checked that you have django_on_heroku being installed on you production environmet? It could be that it's not in your `requirements.txt`, if that's the case, you can `cd` into the directory that contains your `requirements.txt` and use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Once that's done locally, push the changes to either github if you are using automated deploys or use `heroku push` [as per heroku cli docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)